# Какой есть минус у двоичного, гнездового и адресного поиска, а у последовательного нет?

Tags: структуры, структуры-данных

Появился вопрос про то, какой есть минус у двоичного, гнездового и адресного поиска в отличии от метода последовательного поиска помимо того, что данные изначально должны быть отсортированы.

Comment: Из вышеназванных только последовательный поиск можно использовать, когда нет произвольного доступа к хранилищу данных, а есть только последовательный, например, когда данные хранятся на магнитной пленке.

Comment: Если массив маленький (несколько десятков элементов), то последовательный поиск (в современных компьютерах), как ни странно, будет быстрее. Я не шучу. На самом деле все они сконструированы так, что последовательный доступ к памяти (даже к кэшу первого уровня), быстрее переносит данные в регистровый файл с которым и оперируют инструкции сравнения. Кроме того, в остальных алгоритмах поиска для обеспечения одного сравнения потребуется большее количество инструкций

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответы, но, к сожалению, это не совсем то, что хотел услышать препод. Ответ на мой вопрос: при последовательном поиске мы можем искать дизъюнктивно по двум полям. То есть: можно найти либо сотрудника с фамилией Иванов, либо сотрудника с зп 25000.